# How to get correct grammar in the bibliography of a German document when the editor is an association?

Tags: biblatex, german, biblatex-chicago, grammar

I’m writing a German document with the `biblatex-chicago` package.
One of my sources is a journal article where one editor is an association (a Verband).

When I compile the code, the grammar in the bibliography is incorrect.
It reads “Herausgegeben von Fachverband Latexology und John Doe.” whereas “von” should be “vom”.
How can I fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainlanguage[variant=german, spelling=new, latesthyphen=true]{german}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@article{myers_how_2017,
    title = {How to become a Latex professional},
    issn = {1234-5678},
    pages = {33--55},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Sophisticated Journal on Latex},
    author = {Myers, Mike},
    editor = {{Fachverband Latexology} and Doe, John},
    date = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{literature}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very dirty and situational fix: `editor = {{dem Fachverband Latexology} and Doe, John},`, doesn't give 'vom', but 'von dem'. But that could be better because of 'John Doe' anyway.

Comment: @moewe and Ulrike Fischer:
Thank you, both of your solutions work well, and since the problem onIy occurs once in my document, I won’t hesitate to apply one of them.
However, if you are aware of a more general solution and write it up together with the mentioned fixes, it would make a beautiful answer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are looking for a one-shot solution, you could add

```
 execute={\expandafter\def\csname abx@lstr@byeditor\endcsname{Herausgegeben vom}}
```

to your bib-entry.

A more general solution would need some switches in the language strings (\ifwhatever{vom}{von}) and some bib field to set this switches -- possible but unclear if it is really worth the time ...-

Comment: This works like a charm.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, this workaround seems to work only for biblatex-chicago -  Am I right? (I'm using plain biblatex, and it does not seem to work.)

Comment: To (hopefully) bring back @lAtExFaN's question to attention: How does one need to change the above to make it work in plain biblatex? Inserting the suggested code does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 8):

This is one of the limitations of `biblatex`'s localisation system.

As a dirty fix you can include 'dem' into the editor field

```
editor = {{dem Fachverband Latexology} and Doe, John},
```

This will give good output only if the editor is used in the 'herausgegeben von ' position. If it is used as in ' (Hg.)' this will not work correctly.

Since the citations give the short form you can use

```
editor = {{\ifbibliography{dem }{}Fachverband Latexology} and Doe, John},
```

to fix that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you mentioned, it works well within the bibliography, but mixes up a full citation inside a footnote.

Comment: @Philipp I could find a work-around for that problem, but this attempt at a solution certainly has its limits.